Movie with campers and a story teller whose stories are animated?
So when I was little (I'm 19 now), I watched this movie all the time about these campers that sneak out of their cabins late at night and find a campfire. 
There is a black guy who sits with them and starts sharing stories. One was about an old lady who called a window washer. The problem was that the man she called had an accent and sounded like he was saying, "I Vant to Vash your Vindows!" She was so scared until the man came to the door and was completely harmless. 
Another story he told involved something that I'm not real clear about. I can only remember tiny flashes of it. I think it involved a guy and girl and a dog. then I think a waterfall is shown sometime during it. I don't know. Anyways, the word "Moon" or "Moonlight" keeps popping up in my head. 
Each story was animated, but the movie itself with the campers was live action. 
It was definitely made before 2000's i think between 1980's and 1999.

I know the first story as 'The Viper', it's a rather famous joke\urban legend. I think it was a punchline in a GI Joe episode once, but I didn't know it was in a movie.

I poked around a bit and I couldn't find a film with this legend, but if it helps, it's known as "I am the viper", "The viper is coming" and "Vinder Viper" [window wiper]. It's mentioned on Wikipedia as a variation of 'The Babysitter and the Man Upstairs", is included in Alvin Schwartz's book Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark and was referenced on GI Joe, Animaniacs and Teen Titans. Maybe these details will lead you there.

You're looking for the Golden Book Video Campfire Thrillers from 1990. I'm not surprised you couldn't find it; it's not even on IMDb or Wikipedia! From a Youtube synopsis:

One of the Hard and Fast Rules at summer camp is to hit the hay when the counselor says, "Lights out!" But tonight things are feel different. Some of the boys in Pete's cabin are restless. Some of them think that maybe tonight is the night. Tonight may be the night they meet Tallow Glee [the Storyteller].

Tallow Glee is played by a black man and he tells the kids 3 campfire tales (which are animated). You can see the one with the window cleaner (AKA The Viper) in this clip around 4:40:




Edited to include more info, if you don't mind.
